# Maven creates empty jar files

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to create a jar file using maven but the generated jar is empty and contains only the META-INF folder. It doesn't contains the classes.

This is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>my-commons</name>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: How are the files in your project organized?

Comment: In the project I have pom.xml, resources, src and target. Inside src I have META-INF and com. Inside com all the packages

Comment: Try in Eclipse, Create new Maven project.

Comment: "Try in Eclipse"? Maven should work from the command line. Period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A default file hierarchy for Maven projects looks like this:

```
src/
    main/
         java/
              com/
                  mycompany/
                            Main.java
```

there could be test/... right beside main/. Also You may configure source directory with the  <sourceDirectory> tag (a child of the <build> tag). See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html for more examples

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

After the `artifactId` and then run `mvn package`.

Comment: No, he has sources in the place which contradicts with maven default file hierarchy.

Comment: No need to give packaging jar, cause it's the default.